# I’m facing drastic slowness in my web Appa running on containerd and kubernetes vs docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I’m using containerd runtime for kubernetes ….

When I compare the performance in the same node, same container in docker vs kubernetes, the build load time is 17sec in docker and 55 sec in k8….
The page load time is 2 sec in docker and 30 sec in k8…

The container has tomcat, cassandra, redis in it.

What an I missing ?

I tried without setting resource limit and with limit 10 cores and 4Gi RAM

Maybe containerd is slower than docker ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried changing from dontainerd to cri-dockerd and still facing the same issue.